# Joining strings and writing to cvs gives "" and (

Tags: python

I'm joining two strings together and printing them to a csv, my result is this

```
"('Hail, Caesar!', '2016')"
"('Pride and Prejudice and Zombies', '2016')"
"('Home Invasion', '2016')"
```

but i want it like this

```
Hail, Caesar!,2016
Pride and Prejudice and Zombies, 2016
```

my actual code is

```
for u in response_data:
    titolo = u['title'].encode('utf-8')
    anno = u['release_date']
    anno1 = str(anno[:4])
    output = titolo, anno1
    writertitolo.writerow([output])
```

how can i fix this? response_data is a JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
for u in response_data:
    titolo = u['title'].encode('utf-8')
    anno = u['release_date']
    anno1 = str(anno[:4])
    output = titolo, anno1
    writertitolo.writerow(output)
```

When you do

```
output = titolo, anno1
```

`output` will contain the value `(titolo, anno1)`,

Now what you are writing to csv is

`[output]`

This will translate into `[(titolo, anno1)]`

What you need to write to csv is `[titolo, anno1]`

Answer (score 2):

[`csv.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) takes an iterable and writes the elements of that iterable.

In your case, `output` is already a tuple of `titolo` and `anno1`. So when you write `[output]` you actually get `[(titolo, anno1)]` which is a list with a single: a tuple. So when you write that one item, it gets converted to a string which causes the result you see.

Instead, you want to pass the tuple directly:

```
writertitolo.writerow(output)
```